# BASH: allow users to FTP files to my server without revealing FTP login credentials to them

Tags: macos, bash, shell, ftp, code-access-security

I have an OSX program written with BASH scripts. I want to enable anyone who has this program downloaded to be able to FTP files to my server (and associate it with their account for them to access the stuff, of course) WITHOUT allowing the user access to the FTP login/access credentials. How do I do this?

I already have experience with BASH/Shell, Java, and Procedural C++, so if it can be done with one of these programming languages, that would be preferable. However, Any suitable answer will suffice.

if it is possible to provide an enterprise- or professional-level of security for the FTP login credentials, that would be most helpful.

I don't need advice on managing user accounts or managing their access to exclusively their information. I only mentioned that to illustrate the context in which it will operate. An indefinite number of users need to be able to access and store their things on the same server.

This functionality doesn't REQUIRE an FTP-based solution. Any suitable solution will suffice.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that. The information has to be on their computer.

Comment: You want "enterprise" level security for login credentials without actually using login credentials? You might get away with an HTTP or REST app that stores the user's uploaded objects in a (nosql perhaps) database. But without some kind of authentication, there's no way to prevent one user from spoofing as another.

Comment: Down vote due to sheer ridiculousness of question

Comment: Don't be a prick. its only ridiculous to those who understand. I'm clearly still learning. Take your eliteism elsewhere. I'm a student. This question clearly doesn't deserve the level of scrutiny and spite you give it.

Answer (score 0):

If an application needs an access to a remote system that requires credentials, the credentials have to be stored somewhere in the application.

All you can do is to make the credentials hard to find in the application (obfuscate them).

What is particularly difficult, if the application is scripted, as is your case.

See [Obfuscating stored passwords in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9828202/850848).

Comment: i don't want the ftp login/access details in the script. If it is in a scirpt, i need to prevent users from being able to view the ftp login/access credentials.

Comment: this includes ANY computer user, admin, or any programmer/hacker who just so happens to be using the account. I essentially need to obfuscate the contents of the script while allowing it to execute properly.

Comment: I have included a reference to a related question detailing this. Simply you cannot really hide the credentials.