# Encrypt username and password on batch script

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to load flat file into server through FTP using batch files. I'm aware of the scripts and I'm able to transfer the file to server. Currently I'm following this below method.

```
@echo off
title File Transfer
color 3F
cd "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Access\"
echo -
echo - Transferring File to Server. Please be patient... 
echo -
echo - Closing this window will Terminate the entire process 
ftp -n -s:"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Access\ftp.txt" server_name >"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Access\ftp.log"
```

Script File Code: (`ftp.txt`)

```
User Userid password
mkdir App
put "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Access\File.txt"   "App/File.txt"
quit
```

My requirement is that I should not display username and password on the script file. These credential information dynamically coming from the variables and I'm generating this batch file and script file dynamically.

Kindly any experts suggest me solution which makes more sense to accomplish this requirement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You generally cannot encrypt anything while still allowing it to be decrypted automatically.

See for example [BASH: allow users to FTP files to my server without revealing FTP login credentials to them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28864791/850848)

---

All you can typically do is to obfuscate the credentials. But the Windows `ftp.exe` does not allow even that.

With `ftp.exe`, you can use input redirection to somewhat reduce the risk:

```
(
echo user %USERNAME% %PASSWORD%
echo mkdir ...
echo put ...
echo quit
) | ftp.exe -n example.com
```